# How to check an IP address is within a predefined list in python

Tags: python, sockets, comparison

Providing that I have this list which contains a number IP addresses:

```
IpAddresses = ["192.168.0.1","192.168.0.2","192.168.0.3","192.168.0.4"]
```

Then after receiving a packet I want to check if its source address is included in the predefined list IpAddresses

```
data, address = rxsocket.recvfrom(4096)
```

I have tried two alternatives, but both didn't work:

First:

```
if (address in IpAddresses):
    do something
```

Then, I tried to convert address into string before making the comparison:

```
str_address = str(address)
if (str_address in IpAddresses):
    do something
```

I am not familiar with python syntax, so please could you show me how to do this.

Comment: try printing  `address` is it raw  byte string ? or is it ascii dot notation ...

Comment: print ("Resp IP is: ", address) gives this output:                                       ('Resp IP is: ', ('192.168.0.3', 30490))

Comment: Please use `code` formatting in your question and provide the specific comparison and output.

Comment: It seems that "address" is tuple that contains both address and port.

Comment: If you are using Python 3.x, you might want to checkout [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) and this [intro](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/ipaddress.html#ipaddress-howto).  It could be helpful, particularly if you have more sophisticated processing in mind down the road.

Comment: Actually I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if address[0] in IpAddresses:
```

since the address object appears as a tuple only the 0th index appears in your list so you should check for its existence (also you can usually skip the parenthesis on an if statement unless it makes the if statement less readable)